# How to enable font smoothing for specific fonts?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, fonts, anti-aliasing, smoothing

I prefer disabled font anti-aliasing on my desktop, but some websites use custom fonts that look absolutely horrible without anti-aliasing. I could disable custom fonts completely from Firefox font options, but it'd be better if there was a way to create a list of fonts that are ok to smooth (or better a list of fonts that should not be smoothed and allow all others).

Is there a way to (not) smooth specified fonts in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to defer to a browser plugin which will change the markup after it is downloaded. Likely what you'll have to do is make it change the font altogether, as there is no way to enable / disable font smoothing (the browser internally determines that based on the 2D rendering engine).

Example plugin - Greasemonkey: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: So will that plugin make it possible to display a list of specified fonts aliased, and the rest anti-aliased? Because if not, as I said in the question, I could disable custom fonts in options. It's all there in the Firefox version of the browser.